# laravel: config file name convention?

Tags: php, laravel

`foo_constants.php` or `fooConstants.php`?

It seems laravel would do some name conversion when you use `Config::get('...')`,  which one do you use?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`foo.php`

Why specify `constants` at all? Convention I've generally seen is single word filenames.  I think in general most 'config' type settings will be constant in an environment even if it is variable between environments.

Take a look at the [aws/aws-sdk-php-laravel](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-php-laravel/blob/master/config/config.php) composer package as an example.  That file is named `config.php` in the package, but gets published to `aws.php`.

[rydurham/Sentinel](https://github.com/rydurham/Sentinel/blob/master/src/config/config.php) is another popular package. It also only has a single-word filename.

**Update**

In the situation you describe in your comment, I would do something like this:

```
<?php // File: foo.php
  return [
      'sheep' => [
          'clothing' => 'wool',
          'chews_on' => 'cud',
      ],
      'wolf' => [
          'clothing' => 'fur',
          'chews_on' => 'sheep',
      ],

  ];
```

And you can access both of those via `Config::get('foo.sheep')` and `Config::get('foo.wolf')`, respectively.  When they're defined on the server, they're still 'on the server' so to speak.  If you wish to release the values stored in `foo.sheep` to the public you can, and you can do so without also exposing `foo.wolf`.

Comment: cus I wanna use constants in both backend end and as public api. so I wonder if i can name one config file `sheep_constants` and another `wolf_constants`.

Comment: I updated my answer with what I believe would be the conventional way of handling that situation.  Hope this helps.

Comment: AWS Laravel Repository use now snake_case as we can see from the repository: https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-php-laravel/tree/master/config